# How to deal with NaN when they make up 45% of the data?

Tags: python, panel-data, missing-data, operations-research

I compare two countries (Germany and Sweden) and have 30 variables over 15 (2001-2016) years. Unfortunately, the first years (2001-2007) for Sewden and (2001-2006) for Germany have NaN (missing values). That is about 45% of my dataset.

Here is a part of my dataset

```
             government_support_and_policies  taxes_and_bureaucracy  \
```

`year country

2001 Sweden                               NaN                    NaN

...
2007 Sweden                               NaN                    NaN

2010 Sweden                              2.53                   1.94

...
2016 Sweden                              2.31                   2.38

...

2006 Germany                              NaN                    NaN`

The data was collected from different sources that is why some variables have enough observation over the years and some of them have considerable amout of missing values inside.

execution of this code, provide us with the information about the number of missing values for each variable.

```
N_missing = []
```

`for name in col_names:
    M0 = df1[name].isnull().sum()
    N_missing.append(M0)
print(N_missing)
for n in range(0, len(col_names)):
    print(col_names[n],':', N_missing[n])`

Output:

`code : 0
financing_for_entrepreneurs : 13
government_support_and_policies : 13
taxes_and_bureaucracy : 13
governmental_programs : 13
basic_school_entrepreneurial : 13
post_school_entrepreneurial : 13
P_and_D_transfer : 13
com_and_prof_infrastructure : 13
internal_market_dynamics : 13
internal_market_openness : 13
physical_and_services_infrast : 13
cultural_and_social_norms : 13
perceived_opportunities : 0
perceived_capabilities : 0
fear_of_failure_rate : 0
entrepreneurial_intentions : 0
total_entrepreneurial_activity : 0
established_business_ownership : 0
entrepr_employee_activity : 0
motivational_index : 0
female_male_TEA : 2
f_m_oppotunity_driven_TEA : 4
high_job_creation_expectation : 4
innovation : 16
business_services_sector : 18
high_status_to_successful_entr : 19
entrep_as_a_good_career_choise : 23`

`df1.shape
(29, 28)`

So I cannot get rid of the years with missing values 2001-2006 because in this case I reduce my dataset significantly. What should I do with these missing values? How can I reasonably fill them (should I use my data set to forecast the values? What techniques can you recommend?) My question relates to the variables that have 13 missing values or less.

The purpose of the dataset is to analyse the differences in factors that influence innovation in Germany and Sweden. However, for variable "innovation" there are 16 points of data, that are not available. So I might want to use something else instead of `innovation` variable. In general, kind of panel regression was planed to use.

Here is the link for dataset [100data](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/7Qy1/akQY5yNBH)

Comment: You don't "reduce a dataset significantly" when you get rid of NaNs: by definition, you never had those data in the first place. You simply don't have any data for the years 2001-2006.

Comment: You are right but for some variables like `entrepr_employee_activity` (as well as `motivational_index`, `high_job_creation_expectation`) I do have data for all years. That is why I am not sure what exactly should I do. Should I drop variables with a large percentage of missing values?

Comment: That's an important detail you need to include in the question.  Currently it suggests *all* your variables are NA for the years 2001-2006.  It's important to explain *why* these data are missing, too, because the procedures differ according to the reasons for missingness.

Comment: You haven't actually said what you want to do with the data, but most likely you want to use a model that can easily handle missing data (e.g. state space models), and not try to "fill in" the gaps unless you really need them. Also, minor nitpick: NaN is a specific value in the IEEE floating point standard, the result of certain kinds of operations which don't yield "numbers". Some software encodes a missing value as "NaN" as an implementation detail (i.e. as a dummy value), but a missing value is not "a NaN".